# React State update with button click from another component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

**Please read the details below of code**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snxHR.jpg)

**This MegaMenu Component**

```
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import './MegaMenu.css';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import ArrowRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowRight';

const categories = [
  "Sunglass",
  "Footwear",
  "Men Watch",
  "Women Watch",
  "Computer",
  "SmartPhones",
  "Camera",
];

const MegaMenu = () => {

  return (
    <div className='mega_menu_component'>
      <div className='mega_menu_Items'>
        <div className='mega_menus'>
          <MenuIcon className='mega_menu_icon' style={{ fontSize: '40px', color: '#fff', cursor: 'pointer' }} />
          <div class="menu_link_content">
            <NavLink className="menu_name" to="/">Home</NavLink>
            <NavLink className="menu_name" to="/products">Shop <ArrowRightIcon style={{ fontSize: 'medium' }} />

              <ul className="categoryMenu">
                {categories.map((categoryName) => (
                  <li className="categoryMenu-link" > <NavLink style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: '#000' }} key={categoryName} to={`/products/${categoryName}`}>{categoryName}</NavLink></li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink className="menu_name" to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
            <NavLink className="menu_name" to="/about">About</NavLink>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MegaMenu;
```

```
**This Product Component**
```

```
    import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Products.css";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { clearErrors, getProduct } from "../../actions/productAction";
import Loader from "../layout/Loader/Loader";
import ProductCard from "../Home/ProductCard";
import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import { useAlert } from "react-alert";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import MetaData from "../layout/MetaData";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
import { NavLink, useLocation } from "react-router-dom"
const categories = [
  "Sunglass",
  "Footwear",
  "Men Watch",
  "Women Watch",
  "Computer",
  "SmartPhones",
  "Camera",
];

const Products = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  const urlLocation = useLocation();
  const categoryName = urlLocation.pathname.split('/')[2];
  const alert = useAlert();

  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState([0, 25000]);

    // const [category, setCategory] = useState(categoryName);


    const [category, setCategory] = useState('');
 

  const [ratings, setRatings] = useState(0);


  const {
    products,
    loading,
    error,
    productsCount,
    resultPerPage,
    filteredProductsCount,
  } = useSelector((state) => state.products);

  const keyword = match.params.keyword;

  const setCurrentPageNo = (e) => {
    setCurrentPage(e);
  };

  const priceHandler = (event, newPrice) => {
    setPrice(newPrice);
  };
  let count = filteredProductsCount;


  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }
    dispatch(getProduct(keyword, currentPage, price, category, ratings));
  }, [dispatch, keyword, currentPage, price, category, ratings, alert, error]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <MetaData title="PRODUCTS -- ECOMMERCE" />
          <h2 className="productsHeading">Products</h2>

          <div className="products">
            {products &&
              products.map((product) => (
                <ProductCard key={product._id} product={product} />
              ))}
          </div>

          <div className="filterBox">
            <Typography>Price</Typography>
            <Slider
              value={price}
              onChange={priceHandler}
              valueLabelDisplay="auto"
              aria-labelledby="range-slider"
              min={0}
              max={25000}
            />

            <Typography>Categories</Typography>
            <ul className="categoryBox">
              {categories.map((category) => (
                <li className="category-link" >
                  <NavLink style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'black' }} key={category} onClick={() => setCategory(category)} to={`/products`}>{category}</NavLink>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
            <fieldset>
              <Typography component="legend">Ratings Above</Typography>
              <Slider
                value={ratings}
                onChange={(e, newRating) => {
                  setRatings(newRating);
                }}
                aria-labelledby="continuous-slider"
                valueLabelDisplay="auto"
                min={0}
                max={5}
              />
            </fieldset>
          </div>


          {resultPerPage < count && (
            <div className="paginationBox">
              <Pagination
                activePage={currentPage}
                itemsCountPerPage={resultPerPage}
                totalItemsCount={productsCount}
                onChange={setCurrentPageNo}
                nextPageText="Next"
                prevPageText="Prev"
                firstPageText="1st"
                lastPageText="Last"
                itemClass="page-item"
                linkClass="page-link"
                activeClass="pageItemActive"
                activeLinkClass="pageLinkActive"
              />
            </div>
          )}
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

**When I want to click on the mega menu "Shop>>Category" name the url would be like http://localhost:3000/products/Sunglass**
**Here sunglass is category name**
**Now I want to data update in the Product component (ProductCard Update) using the URL category part. But it does not work. **

**How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? What is the issue? Is there an error? It's not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Anyone Can give a response to the problem.??

Comment: Probably not until it's stated what the problem/issue is? The post appears to need some more detail and clearly state what any issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of possible solutions is to handle pathname change using history.listen method (https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/dev/docs/api-reference.md#historylistenlistener-listener)

The code may look something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = history.listen(({ action, location }) => {
      // Do your magic
    })

    // Don't forget to unsub
    return unlisten
}, [])
```

Comment: I am confused about your response. can you explain the details? please pleaase